# How to restructure a list of lists in C++ using splice()

Tags: c++, list, splice

I have a `list` of `lists` with elements of type `my_struct`. I go through every element with two iterators (one for the outer list and one for the inner lists) and do some calculations. Every time I passed an inner list, I check a criterion and (if necessary) try to split this inner list into two, using the `splice()` function. I want to relocate the second part of the inner list to the outer list (right after the current inner list).

Here is what I've got so far:

```
std::list<std::list<my_struct>> myList;
std::list<std::list<my_struct>>::iterator outerIter;
std::list<my_struct>::iterator innerIter;

for (outerIter = myList.begin(); outerIter != myList.end(); outerIter++)
{
    std::list<my_struct> &listEntry = *outerIter;

    for (innerIter = listEntry.begin(); innerIter != listEntry.end(); innerIter++)
    {
        // some calculations
    }

    if (criterion)
    {
        myList.splice(outerIter, listEntry, innerIter, listEntry.end());
    }
}
```

What this code shall do is to relocate the `std::list<my_struct>` beginning at `innerIter` and ending at `listEntry.end()` as a new inner list just behind the currently checked inner list.

I hope that you can understand what I mean, as I don't know how to explain that more understandable.

I already tried out different ways of writing the `splice` part, but I always received errors.

So, if anybody has an idea on how to correctly program this, then I would be very glad to get some help.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is how the line with the `splice()` function is written correctly.

Comment: When I debug, I get `error C2664` saying that the second parameter `listEntry` can't be converted to `std::list<_Ty> &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you have missundertood what the [splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) function do.

The problem I can see at first glance is that you're passing the iterator `innerIter` to `splice` **but** that iterator is not pointing to the begining any more, since you incremented it in the previous for loop.

**And the main problem:**

You are trasfering elements of type `my_struct` to a `std::list<std::list<my_struct>>` list. Hence the compilation error you're getting: You can't convert `my_struct` to `std::list<my_struct>`, if you search for the detailed error you will find that `_Ty` is indeed `my_struct`.

So, this is what you have to do:

1. Create the new list that will reveice the elements.
2. transfer the elements.
3. Insert new list at the position you want.

In C++ (*warning not tested*):

```
for (auto outerIter = myList.begin(); outerIter != myList.end(); outerIter++)
{
    std::list<my_struct> &listEntry = *outerIter;

    for (auto innerIter = listEntry.begin(); innerIter != listEntry.end(); innerIter++)
    {
        // some calculations
    }

    if (criterion)
    {
        // you need point the next element, in roder to insert after the current outerIter position. 
        MyList::iterator tmp = outerIter;
        std::list<my_struct> list_to_insert;                                                            // 1
        list_to_insert.splice(list_to_insert.begin(), listEntry, listEntry.begin(), listEntry.end());   // 2
        myList.insert(++tmp, list_to_insert);                                                   // 3
    }
}
```

Comment: As I declared `listEntry` as `std::list<my_struct> &listEntry = *outerIter;`, I thought that it's of type `std::list<my_struct>&` and not of type `my_struct`. Maybe that was the error in my thinking.
I tried to use the 5th constructor proposed in your link.
I also tried your version, but I get an error `C2784` saying _"std::move_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &)": template argument for "const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &" can't be derived from "int"_ (I hope that I translated it correctly).

Comment: I already had something similar before where I wanted to add an `int` to an `iterator`.
By the way: instead of passing `innerIter` to `splice` I would like to use something like `idx = distance(listEntry.begin(), innerIter);` and add it, but that's where I got an error before and therefore started to rewrite everything...

Comment: I think the error was in the `+` operation with the interator, I have edited the answer.

Comment: That seems to work. (I just get another error now, but that's ok)
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. That's very kind of you! I often have syntax problems... :(
I try to calculate the crossProduct for a cv::Point3d (I'm using OpenCV). The code looks like this: `crossProduct(outerIter->begin()->pt3D, outerIter->end()->pt3D)` saying "calculate the cross product of the first and last 3D-point in the list" (the 3D point is one element in `my_struct`).
I get an error saying that the _list iterator is not dereferencable_, but I can't figure out why.
I just recently found out that the first time I call the function, `outerIter->empty()` returns true. That's where I am at the moment...

Comment: Ok. I could make `outerIter->empty()` returning `false` now. But I still get the same error when trying to calculate the crossProduct.

Comment: I changed the code to `crossProduct(outerIter->front().pt3D, outerIter->back().pt3D)` and now it's working. But I don't understand why as I just started using lists and I'm not yet familiar with it...

Comment: By the way: Is there a possibility to reduce the outerIter (like `--outerIter`) after `myList.insert(++tmp, list_to_insert);` as I would like to check the first part of the list that I just cut into two again and I only get an error that I can't decrement it (I first thought it's bidirectional - not only the list itself, but that obviously wrong).

Comment: Can I ask something again? Why is splice not able to copy a part of an innerList to the outerList? I still don't get it... I mean: the splittet list would have the correct type...
Sorry for the many questions!

Comment: Ok, there are enough material there for another question, post another question, and I will check it(and more important, others fellows too).